# HTML - Button - How to make it linkable?

Tags: css, html

I have a button like so:

```
<button>Click Me</button>
```

I want to make that button linked with an href. Is it compliant HTML to wrap the button in a  tag or to put the tag inside of the button to make it linkable?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a link, then it's a link. Make it an anchor tag. If you want it to LOOK like a button, then style it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may just want to use a link itself and style it like a button. You can still add an onclick, but it makes linking to a new page really easy.

```
a.button{
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

A less appealing (though commonly used) method is to wrap a link around an image.

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/mypage"><img src="/images/button.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way would be to put the button in a form, and set the form's action attribute to the page you want to link to and the button's type attribute to submit. 
e.g.

```
<form action="nextpage.html" method="get">
   <button type="submit"> Next </button>
</form>
```