# four forms, Four buttons, four links, one page. Is there a better way?

Tags: forms

I have a page that will have multiple buttons, and I want each button to take the user to a different place. I've searched all over for tutorials, and can't figure out what to do. I have this in the body:

```
<form method="get" action="KFC.html">
    <input type="submit" value="KFC">
</form>

<form method="get" action="Pizza_Hut.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Pizza Hut">
</form>


<form method="get" action="Olive_Garden.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Olive Garden">
</form>


<form method="get" action="Create_Order.html">
    <input type="Submit" value="Create Your Own Order">
</form>

</body>
```

How do I make multiple buttons on one page that go to different places? Is this right? it works but I was told this is a really bad method.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to mess up your code like this? Use simple anchor tags and style them as buttons if you need.

Comment: I'm trying to fix my code, I'm new at this. Can you please be descriptive on how to do this? I appreciate at least getting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. Turns out You would want something very similar to answers above. But for some reason I wasn't understanding.
here is my html code:

```
<body>
<p>Deliveries<p>
<a href="KFC_Menu.html">KFC</a>  #This part -> >KFC</a> gives you the text that appears on the button. The <a href="KFC_Menu.html"> will take you to the KFC_Menu page.

<br>
<a href="Create_Order.html">Create Your Own Order</a>
```

To Style those links to look like buttons make a CSS file like this as an example:

stylesheet.css

```
a {
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 24px;
font-family: sans-serif, arial;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: blue;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 8px;
border: 2px solid grey;
border-radius: 10px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try to add standard browser independent anchor links and then use CSS to style them too look like the buttons you want.

```
 <a href="KFC.html" class="button">KFC</a>
 <a href="Pizza_hut.html" class="button">Pizza hut</a>
```

Etcetera...

Then CSS. In my example below I show one way of styling the links like buttons, Im sure you can find many other more suitable looks if you search for it.

```
a.button { 
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #999;
   background: #aaa;
   color: #333;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
 a.button:hover {
   background: #ccc;
 }
```

I added a class "button" so you only style certain links as buttons. This way you can add as many "buttons" you want without adding forms to your code, and without affecting other links on your page.

Comment: this has absolutely no explanation as to what is going on here. such as what the CSS :hover tag is and how to use it. nor do you explain what any of the CSS actually stand for nor do you give a link to help explain it. The poster is looking for an explanation not to copy paste code.

Comment: @nomad101 Wow, as if you explain what a javascript function is and works, with pros and cons for the solution. Your solution works, but its unneccesary complicated.

Comment: its one line of code that is perfectly self explanitory. do you need someone to explain what window.location means? If you look through the comments I explain everything he wants to know as well as provide links to help him further. Posting a bunch of code is useless to anyone who wants to actually learn.

Comment: Youre not telling him the oddities of the window.location object and the possible browser specific implications not using window.location.href could have for the function of the links. Youre not telling him the obvious difference between standard anchors and js links and that there still is a few specific areas of browser situations where javascript is non-standard and thus should be avoided.

Comment: I completely agree that there are some oddities with using it. However seeing as the poster has very little programming knowledge these oddities would most likely over complicate the issue instead of giving him a good starting location and the information to continue learning. Also those oddities tend to appear on older browsers, which sans from production code can be a second thought to most hobby programmers.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your help. I don't know if I followed your advice exactly, but what I ended up doing was using links.

Comment: sorry, Enter was supposed to be a line break not a submit comment. I did some CSS and edited all the links to look the same. It works and I really appreciate you guys!

Comment: @JohnCurry Great. What I think (as can clearly be read from my arguments with Nomad) using only standard HTML and CSS is always the primary path to follow especially when working on such important thing as navigation. I can't imagine much more annoying things while going to a web page than buttons or links that doesn't work (it happens!).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple forms which can cause lag and issues with validation as well. If you want your buttons to go some where in-particular there are a few methods.

You could use onclick attribute to catch the click event and select the correct location based on the button something like this could work.

```
<button type="button" id="1" onclick="window.location = newLocation1;">Click Me 1!</button>
<button type="button" id="2" onclick="window.location = newLocation2;">Click Me 2!</button>
<button type="button" id="3" onclick="window.location = newLocation3;">Click Me 3!</button>
```

Comment: Why use javascript when there is an `<a>` tag?

Comment: Like this? <button type="button" id="1" onclick="School_Menu.html= Create_Order.html;">Create Your Own Order</button>

Comment: jtherman I used buttons because he asked for buttons not links

Comment: I am trying to make the current page all this code is on (School_Menu.html) to link to the page Create_Order.html

Comment: John it seems you have two locations in your onclick, you would want each onclick to have one location applied to one button.

Comment: ahhh ok well if that is the case you want all of the buttons to link to one particular page you can easily set the onclick="window.location = Create_Order.html" you may need to add a path if there is one.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to vote UP your answer, but because I don't have any reputation yet it voted it down looks like.

Comment: No he wants a link that looks like a button... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749581/html-button-how-to-make-it-linkable

Comment: I have four different pages I want to link to. That was just one of them. It looks like I've been searching for the wrong thing. I wasn't aware of the ability to make a link look like a button without it actually being one. I should be able to figure it out with that information. Thanks everyone.

Comment: No problem I am here to help could not care less what the little number by my name says ;). Although the other post is correct as well, what he was doing was using the "a" tag which in html stands for the hyperlink element. and then used CSS to style the link to look like a button. I would take a close look at http://www.w3schools.com/ for a lot of really valuable information on HTML and how to use it. as well as CSS and javascript for when you get a bit more advanced.

Comment: jtherman you are not even linking to the same question. what exactly are you saying?

Comment: The purpose was to show my point. The OP is looking for a way to add links to his page that looks like buttons.